# TypeError while trying to run stanfordnlp's corenlp demo script

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

ds

```
from stanfordnlp.server import CoreNLPClient
import os
os.environ["CORENLP_HOME"] = r'C:\Users\Shreyans\Downloads\stanford-ner-2018-10-16\stanford-ner-2018-10-16'

text = "Chris Manning is a nice person. Chris wrote a simple sentence. He also gives oranges to people."

client = CoreNLPClient(annotators=['tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','ner','depparse','coref'], timeout=30000, memory='8G')
```

The last line gives me the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-16-f102b031b1bd>", line 18, in <module>
    client = CoreNLPClient(annotators=['tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','ner','depparse','coref'], timeout=30000, memory='8G')

  File "C:\Users\Shreyans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stanfordnlp\server\client.py", line 164, in __init__
    super(CoreNLPClient, self).__init__(start_cmd, stop_cmd, endpoint,

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Would anyone know what causes this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should retry with the full distribution.  In your sample code you are just using the NER distribution.

Full distribution is available here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Also it's possible you need to use a different version of Python.  If you upgrade your Python version that could possibly fix the issue.